# Complex Json parser

Tags: json, list, dictionary

I am using python 2.7.12 to extract the quote of the day from www.quotes.rest/qod.json?category=inspire. the response i am getting is in the json format shown below. how do  i now extract the quotes along with copyright information. Thanks

{
    "success": {
        "total": 1
    },
    "contents": {
        "quotes": [
            {
                "quote": "Extend beyond your preconceived limits!",
                "length": "39",
                "author": "Lorii Myers",
                "tags": [
                    "confidence",
                    "inspire",
                    "limit",
                    "self-improvement"
                ],
                "category": "inspire",
                "date": "2017-07-30",
                "permalink": "https://theysaidso.com/quote/JRlytEdrKdV8iSCZCSEh6weF/lorii-myers-extend-beyond-your-preconceived-limits",
                "title": "Inspiring Quote of the day",
                "background": "https://theysaidso.com/img/bgs/man_on_the_mountain.jpg",
                "id": "JRlytEdrKdV8iSCZCSEh6weF"
            }
        ],
        "copyright": "2017-19 theysaidso.com"
    }
}

How do i extract the quote and copyright values. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it....quote_ = data['contents']['quotes'][0]['quote'] for the quote and 
          copyright_ = data['contents']['copyright']. Thanks